# Spark: Use aggregation function on all columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate

Basically, I want to do the following, but without the for-loop:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

for myCol in df.schema.names:
    uniqs[myCol] = df.groupby("colX").agg(F.countDistinct(myCol)).collect()
```

I tried

```
uniqs = df.groupby("colX").agg(F.countDistinct(*df.schema.names)).collect()
```

but that does something else. The reason why I want to avoid the for-loop is that this way, the groupby operation is done n times instead of just the one time, incurring heavy overhead...

I'm on Spark 1.6.2.

Comment: Besides my accepted answer you can look into @mtoto's answer

Comment: No idea how that did not turn up in my search, it is exactly what I was looking for. Clever trick to move the python loop into the aggregation command. Thanks!